# OpenLayers 3 XYZ grid changes center when zooming

Tags: openlayers-3

Whenever I am zooming the map moves a bit ( up/down or left/right ) by like, a tile. How do I make it so it's centered the same way on all zoom levels?

***Edit due to comment***

No, when I zoom in, it doesn't kinda zoom in exactly on the right tiles , it looks like it moves a bit also. I think I have to set the center of the zoom in the middle of the picture, instead of the mouse location. How should I do that?

Comment: Do you want to lock the center?

Comment: No, when I zoom in, it doesn't kinda zoom in exactly on the right tiles , it looks like it moves a bit also

Comment: @JonatasWalker For the zooming mechanic I guess.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Would you able to show this online?

Comment: I've uploaded a quick video of what it looks like. If you pay attention you can see that it doesn't exactly zoom properly. Especially when using the shift-click zoom it doesn't zoom on the area I selected. The video is here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHIxFEopPcw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Sorry, it looks like all right for me. Maybe someone else can help you with this thread.

Comment: Check it when I use the shift+click box zoom. You can clearly see that it's not zooming on the right place.